# How do I have grass regrown on a lawn without restricting traffic?

Tags: lawn, grass, lawn-repair

Here goes a picture of some location in Eastern Europe. The plant with roundish leaves is *Plantago* and it totally belongs there.

So in the right upper corner is asphalt road. Left of the scene (not visible) is a publicly accessible well. People drive their cars to these scene to get water from the well. When they park on the lawn and then drive away from there they damage the lawn with the wheels. You see the results:

[image: lawn damaged by wheels]

It was covered in grass (some uncool plants but better than dirt) for years and then perhaps two years ago this damage first appeared.

It'd be nice to have grass again on this lawn - it can be any plant that looks like grass and is suitable for a lawn.

This is public area - land belongs to the municipality. That might be formally illegal but most likely seeding anything or dumping some sand or ground there won't bother anyone. However restricting access there would most likely cause resistance and maybe even authorities involved.

How can this lawn be restored to some nice looking condition without restricting traffic to it?

Comment: Related: [how do I strengthen a lawn/verge](https:/gardening.stackexchange.com/q/30272/7288) -- this goes into more detail about the grid stuff, and also discusses adding stone/gravel (which is probably insufficient here)

Answer (score 5):

Best bet would be to use one of the many "lawn traffic grid" products, in either cement or plastic, but that would be better done through or with the cooperation of the "authorities" than otherwise. If people will keep driving on it, that gives the greenery a fighting chance.

If people were to stop driving on it, it would recover on its own.

You could sneak in a late-night/early morning sod transplant, but if driven on and not having a grid, it will soon be damaged again.

Answer (score 2):

IF I were you I would just throw down some seed and straw and maybe people won't drive on it because it looks like you're trying to reseed the lawn.  You can just keep doing that until it starts filling back in.

Answer (score 0):

Those grids do not make a great grass support system.  I've seen so many of these and they always look wimpy.  Do you need extra parking off road?  The best yet lamest solution are big boulders that wreck the undercarriage of any vehicle if they were to drive any further than the boundary.

I am seeing absolutely no grass worth protecting at the moment.  I would define an area for cars, use landscape fabric and fill with 4" of crushed gravel.  Then boulders to stop any traffic from rolling on the turf.  I'd get all of those weeds removed (sod cutter), edge with pt 2X4's and stakes, lay the fabric down and fill with 5/8 minus crushed gravel and compact.  You'll have a win win solution allowing for parking on this road and then delineating where the grass begins and traffic ends.  Use sod.  Don't use seed.

What do your codes allow?  It is always nice to play by the game rules or for almost certain one of your neighbors will report you.

Comment: Doing this legally requires a ton of paperwork plus it would only encourage more cars parking and turning there.

Comment: I was thinking of parking space for your needs.  Shoot, I would dig all that stuff up and lay landscape fabric, 4" of gravel and forget anything green.  I am not sure what it is you are hoping to do but one thing for certain those buildings and code people will tell you exactly what you can or can not do...